# Http Status Code 400 vs 412

Tags: api, http, rest, http-status-code-400, http-status-code-412

So I'm developing a Rest API

When a POST is made to create a resource and a required field is missing what should I return?

400 - Bad Request

OR

412 - Precondition Failed

And Why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When is it appropriate to respond with a HTTP 412 error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369480/when-is-it-appropriate-to-respond-with-a-http-412-error)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use 400 if the request **parameters** are wrong. Use 412 if one of the `If-*` request **headers** like [`If-Match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.24), [`If-Modified-Since`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.25), etc are wrong.

Why? That's just what RFC says. See for example this extract of [`If-Match`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.24) specification:

> If none of the entity tags match, or if "*" is given and no current entity exists, the server MUST NOT perform the requested method, and MUST return a 412 (Precondition Failed) response. This behavior is most useful when the client wants to prevent an updating method, such as PUT, from modifying a resource that has changed since the client last retrieved it.

Comment: It also states the request could not be fulfilled due to malformed syntax for 400.

Comment: This page really helped me - http://odino.org/don-t-rape-http-if-none-match-the-412-http-status-code/ - Using 'PUT' requests for context made it easier for me to understand what it's for, as it's always easy to abuse certain status codes.

Answer (score 17):

412 is used when your server does not meet a condition specified by the client.

In your case you should use a 400. It is just a bad request.

See this [link](http://odino.org/don-t-rape-http-if-none-match-the-412-http-status-code/) for some explaination on pre-condition headers.

> The Etag header is, generally, a string that represents our resource
>   in the HTTP headers. You ask for a resource with an If-Match is a
>   preconditional HTTP header. It will send a 412 if it does not match
>   the code you sent.
>
> If-None-Match tells the server to process a whole response only if the
>   Etag is different from the one sent by the client.

Comment: Think someone had a bad day. Just ignore it and let the system do its job :)

Answer (score 5):

You could use status code 422. If you don't want to, 400 is fine.